# Show that in $\mathbb{Q}$[X] there are infinitely many distinct congruence classes modulo X$^2$ − 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that in $\mathbb{Q}$[X] there are infinitely many distinct congruence classes modulo X$^2$ − 2.

Describe them and show that $\mathbb{Q}$[X]/(X$^2$ − 2) is a field.

Not sure how to start this.

Comment: Note that if $ax+b$ and $cx+d$ are distinct polynomials (of degree $\le 1$), they belong to different congruence classes.